# HTML Using local image as background

Tags: html, image, background, local

I have troubles using a local image as my background in HTML. Anyone who maybe can give me an tip on what at l should try to change in order to make the code work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="=text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background: url('file:///C:/Users/skole/Onedrive/NTNU/Annet/Test/bakgrunn.jpeg');">
    </body>
<body>

    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: `background-image:`

Comment: `<img src=”images/ur-image.jpg” />`, put image in src in ur project file

Comment: @HumbleDeveloper01 so l tried using the src function but coud not really figure out what to replace it with, do you maybe have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to image should lead from Your .html file. So, the question is where is Your .html file situated, for example, if it is in folder TEST, path should be: url('./bakgrunn.jpeg') or just url('bakgrunn.jpeg');

Comment: Also note that an HTML document can only have one body tag.

Comment: The background image is located in the folder test including the html file.

Comment: So try as I wrote, also make sure, You have only one <body> tag as 15Rabi wrote.